# Circuit Breaker Tracker

Tags: electrical

I have several plugs that do not have current. I have hooked up a circuit breaker tester to verify which breaker serves them. It seemed to go to the wrong breaker. I removed the transmitter from the plug and rechecked the breakers. The checker is flashing on a breaker without the transmitter being plugged in.

Comment: ...then the product is apparently not very good at its job. However, in the event that all of your breakers are turned on, but you have plugs without current, they might not be well-tracked anyway due to wires not being connected between the breaker and the non-working plug.

Comment: What tester are you using?

Comment: "It seemed to go to the wrong breaker." Why do you think it's the wrong breaker? Sometimes, outlets can be connected to an unexpected circuit for a wide variety of reasons, most of which aren't apparent 30 years after they were installed that way...

Comment: Are they GFCI? (GFCIs can poop out even while the circuit is live)

Comment: OP please confirm: did you expect that since the outlet did not supply power that you expected to see a faulted breaker supplying the line? Note this isn't always the case. Also,  are not all your breakers defaulting to "on" when power is functioning normally?

Comment: I'll hazard a *guess* that our OP has an RCD on the main entry of their "not North-American" house, not GFCIs per breaker/circuit.